# How to build histogram using ScottPlot WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scottplot

I am trying to build basic histogram that is located in examples of ScottPlot [text](https://scottplot.net/cookbook/4.1/category/statistics/#histogram). I can not manage how to join this code to my project Windows Forms App and make it work:

```
 ScottPlot.Version.ShouldBe(4, 1, 70);
    var plt = new ScottPlot.Plot(600, 400);

    // create a histogram with a fixed number of bins
    ScottPlot.Statistics.Histogram hist = new(min: 140, max: 220, binCount: 100);

    // add random data to the histogram
    Random rand = new(0);
    double[] heights = ScottPlot.DataGen.RandomNormal(rand, pointCount: 1234, mean: 178.4, stdDev: 7.6);
    hist.AddRange(heights);

    // show the histogram counts as a bar plot
    plt.AddBar(values: hist.Counts, positions: hist.Bins);

    // customize the plot style
    plt.YAxis.Label("Count (#)");
    plt.XAxis.Label("Height (cm)");
    plt.SetAxisLimits(yMin: 0);

    plt.SaveFig("stats_histogram.png");
```

Could somebody explain how to use basic example with real Plot control? And here is my current code that i have now:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void formsPlot1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateChart();
    }

    void CreateChart()
    {
        ScottPlot.Statistics.Histogram hist = new(min: 140, max: 220, binCount: 100);
        double[] dataX = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        double[] dataY = new double[] { 1, 4, 9, 16, 25 };

        formsPlot1.Plot.AddScatter(dataX, dataY);
        formsPlot1.Refresh();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?  These are two basic blocks of code and you do not mention a specific issue. Questions like "please make this for me" are not well received here.

Answer (score -1):

The code to make ScottPlot alive is very simple:

```
using ScottPlot.Plottable;

namespace nsScottPlot;

public partial class ChartSampleForm : Form {

    ScatterPlot _plot1, _plot2, _plot3; Crosshair _crosshair;

    public ChartSampleForm() { InitializeComponent(); } // ScottPlot.FormsPlot formsPlot1

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs ea) {
        base.OnLoad(ea);
        try {
            dtpStart.Value = new DateTime(2023, 12, 9, 21, 36, 0);
            dtpEnd.Value = new DateTime(2023, 12, 9, 21, 40, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { App.ErrMsgUnexpected(ex, "Load form"); }
    }

    private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            using var db = new MyContext();
            var xa = db.ParameterSets.Where(w => w.Timestamp >= dtpStart.Value && w.Timestamp <= dtpEnd.Value)
                .Select(s => System.Convert.ToDouble(s.Timestamp.ToOADate())).ToArray();
            _plot1 = formsPlot1.Plot.AddScatter(xa, db.ParameterSets.Where(w => w.Timestamp >= dtpStart.Value && w.Timestamp <= dtpEnd.Value)
                .Select(s => (double)s.Tag1).ToArray());
            _plot2 = formsPlot1.Plot.AddScatter(xa, db.ParameterSets.Where(w => w.Timestamp >= dtpStart.Value && w.Timestamp <= dtpEnd.Value)
                .Select(s => (double)s.Tag2).ToArray());
            _plot3 = formsPlot1.Plot.AddScatter(xa, db.ParameterSets.Where(w => w.Timestamp >= dtpStart.Value && w.Timestamp <= dtpEnd.Value)
                .Select(s => (double)s.Tag3).ToArray());
            var plt = formsPlot1.Plot;
            plt.XAxis.DateTimeFormat(true);
            _crosshair = plt.AddCrosshair(xa[0], 0); _crosshair.HorizontalLine.IsVisible = false;
            _crosshair.VerticalLine.PositionFormatter = x => DateTime.FromOADate(x).ToString("T");
            plt.Title("Flowrate"); plt.YLabel("bbl/d"); formsPlot1.Refresh();
            formsPlot1.MouseMove += formsPlot1_MouseMove;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { App.ErrorTraceEx(ex, "Get chart"); }

    }

    private void formsPlot1_MouseMove(object? sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        (double mouseCoordX, _) = formsPlot1.GetMouseCoordinates();
        (_, double pointY, _) = _plot1.GetPointNearestX(mouseCoordX); label8.Text = pointY.ToString("N1");
        (_, pointY, _) = _plot2.GetPointNearestX(mouseCoordX); label7.Text = pointY.ToString("N1");
        (_, pointY, _) = _plot3.GetPointNearestX(mouseCoordX); label6.Text = pointY.ToString("N1");
        _crosshair.X = mouseCoordX; formsPlot1.Refresh(lowQuality: true, skipIfCurrentlyRendering: true);
    }
}
```

[image]